Div not appearing when clicking on a button
I am kinda new to programming, so I'm sorry if my question is silly or the code I'll send is not perfect. I'm trying to build a simple web app in Flask that allows to track your CO2 emissions by inserting some information about your everyday consumptions.
Now, I have a few buttons (for example id="nuovaEmissione") that when clicked a div in the center of the page appears (using javascript .add("active") to the display property of the div) and lets you do other stuff. I applied the same, identic logic to another button (id="obiettivoMensile") and for some reasons the div would not appear.
Please, I'm losing my mind on this, I checked everything. The logic is the same of the other button, but it doesn't work. What can I do?
I tried to check the names of the variables, some spelling mistakes in the javascript but everything is okay. I even asked chatgpt to solve the problem and it says that everything is correct.


document.getElementById('nuovaEmissione').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('tipoEmissione').classList.add('active');
  });

document.getElementById('tipoEmissione').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target === this) {
        this.classList.remove('active');
    }
});

document.getElementById('trasporti').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('tipoTrasporti').classList.add('active');
    document.getElementById('tipoEmissione').classList.remove('active');
});

document.getElementById('tipoTrasporti').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target === this) {
        this.classList.remove('active');
    }
});

document.getElementById('confermaEmissione').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('tipoTrasporti').classList.remove('active');
});


document.getElementById('energia').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('tipoEnergia').classList.add('active');
    document.getElementById('tipoEmissione').classList.remove('active');
});

document.getElementById('tipoEnergia').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target === this) {
        this.classList.remove('active');
    }
});

document.getElementById('confermaEnergia').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('tipoEnergia').classList.remove('active');
});


document.getElementById('cibo').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('tipoCibo').classList.add('active');
    document.getElementById('tipoEmissione').classList.remove('active');
});

document.getElementById('tipoCibo').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target === this) {
        this.classList.remove('active');
    }
});

document.getElementById('confermaCibo').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('tipoCibo').classList.remove('active');
});


document.getElementById('obiettivoMensile').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('setObiettivo').classList.add('active');
});

document.getElementById('obiettivoMensile').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target === this) {
        this.classList.remove('active');
    }
});

document.getElementById('confermaObiettivo').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('setObiettivo').classList.remove('active');
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    
});
#larghezza {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.landing-page {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

#setObiettivo {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#setObiettivo.active {
  display: block;
}

#tipoEmissione {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#tipoEmissione.active {
  display: block;
}

#tipoTrasporti {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#tipoTrasporti.active {
  display: block;
}

#tipoEnergia {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#tipoEnergia.active {
  display: block;
}

#tipoCibo {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  max-width: 300px;
}

#tipoCibo.active {
  display: block;
}

#contenitoreGraficoTorta {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#contenitoreUser {
  height: 250px;
  width: 286px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

#contenitoreCuriosity {
  width: 250px;
  height: 125px;
  float: right;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#contenitoreGraficoLinee {
  width: 578px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#contenitoreListaEmissioni {
  padding: 18px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 250px;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: right;
}

#nuovaEmissione {
  float: left;
}

.scrollable-list {
  max-height: 250px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
}

#listaEmissioni {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.form-control:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(40, 167, 69, 0.25);
}

.form-select:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(40, 167, 69, 0.25);
}
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Dashboard
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
<div class="container-lg">
  <div class="row mt-2 mb-2">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div id="contenitoreGraficoTorta">
        <canvas id="graficoTorta"></canvas>
      </div>
      <div id="contenitoreGraficoLinee">
        <canvas id="graficoLinee" width="800"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
      <div id="contenitoreUser">
        <div class="align-items-center">
          <span class="fs-3">Ciao <span class="text-success fw-medium">{{ username }}</span></span>
          <img src="/static/emojiMano.png" width="40px" height="40px">
        </div>
        <p>Obiettivo mensile</p>
        <div>
          <button id="obiettivoMensile" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">imposta</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
      <div id="contenitoreCuriosity">
        Ciao
      </div>

      <div id="contenitoreListaEmissioni">
        <div class="scrollable-list">
        <ul id="listaEmissioni" class="list-group">
          {% for item in lista_emissioni %}
            {% if item["tipo_emissione"] == "Trasporti" %}
              <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="mt-2">
                    <div class="fw-bold fs-6 text-success">{{ item["tipo_emissione"] }}</div>
                    <p class="text-success">{{ item["data_creazione"] }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="fw-bold fs-6 text-danger ">{{ item["kgCO2"] }} kgCO2</div>
              </li>
            {% elif item["tipo_emissione"] == "Energia" %}
              <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="mt-2">
                    <div class="fw-bold fs-6 text-success">{{ item["tipo_emissione"] }}</div>
                    <p class="text-success">{{ item["data_creazione"] }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="fw-bold fs-6 text-danger">{{ item["kgCO2"] }} kgCO2</div>
              </li>
            {% elif item["tipo_emissione"] == "Cibo" %}
              <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="mt-2">
                    <div class="fw-bold fs-6 text-success">{{ item["tipo_emissione"] }}</div>
                    <p class="text-success">{{ item["data_creazione"] }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="fw-bold fs-6 text-danger">{{ item["kgCO2"] }} kgCO2</div>
              </li>
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      <br>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <button id="nuovaEmissione" class="btn btn-success me-2"><span>+</span></button>
        <div class="fs-6 d-inline-block align-text-center text-success"><strong>Aggiungi emissione</strong></div>
      </div>    
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
      

<div id="setObiettivo">
  ciao
</div>

<div id="tipoEmissione">
  <button id="trasporti" class="btn btn-success">Trasporti</button>
  <button id="energia" class="btn btn-success">Energia</button>
  <button id="cibo" class="btn btn-success">Cibo</button>
</div>

<div class="text-center" id="tipoTrasporti">
  <form action="/dashboard", method="POST">
    <p>Che mezzo hai usato?</p>
    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="trasportiSelect" required>
      <option selected>Scegli mezzo</option>
      <option>Macchina</option>
      <option>Motorino</option>
      <option>Aereo</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <p>Per quanto hai viaggiato?</p>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <input class="form-control" name="kmPercorsi" type="number" required>
      <span class="input-group-text">km</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="confermaEmissione" type="submit">Aggiungi</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="text-center" id="tipoEnergia">
  <form action="/dashboard", method="POST">
    <p>Consumo elettricità questo mese?</p>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <input class="form-control" name="kWh" type="number">
      <span class="input-group-text">kWh</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="confermaEnergia" type="submit">Aggiungi</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="text-center" id="tipoCibo">
  <form action="/dashboard", method="POST">
    <p>A base di cosa è stato maggiormente il tuo pranzo?</p>
    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="ciboSelect" required>
      <option selected>Scegli cibo</option>
      <option>Carne</option>
      <option>Latticini</option>
      <option>Pasta</option>
      <option>Verdura</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <p>Quanto ne hai mangiato?</p>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <input class="form-control" name="gCibo" type="number" required>
      <span class="input-group-text">g</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="confermaEmissione" type="submit">Aggiungi</button>
  </form>
</div>

<script src="/static/index.js"></script>
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    
    // Get the canvas element
    var ctx = document.getElementById('graficoTorta').getContext('2d');

    var labels = {{ labels }};

    var torta = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels: ['Trasporti', 'Energia', 'Cibo'],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "kgCO2",
                    data: labels,
                }
            ]
        }
    })
  })
</script>
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("graficoLinee").getContext("2d");
    Chart.defaults.font.size = 12;

    var consumi_giornalieri = {{ consumi_giornalieri }};

    var linee = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30"],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Consumi",
            data: consumi_giornalieri
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            position: 'top',
          },
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Emissioni mensili',
          }
        },
        scales: {
          x: {
            ticks: {
              maxTicksLimit: 30
            }
          }
        }
      },
    })
  })
</script>
{% endblock %}




Is it .active {display: block;}?

Could you please provide a whole page html? By adding console.log in event handlers, you can see if it's executed correctly. Also by opening inspect view using F12 key, you can see if the class name is added. Or you can try with !impossible

looks working with the code you provided. I am editing a snippet to check

Seems to work in the Snippet, please clarify

Hi, try adding a console.log(document.getElementById('obiettivoMensile')) before your event listener. Sometimes it happens that one places the event listener before the object exists, so the event is never triggered. If the event is not triggered, most likely you need to move the event listener to the bottom of the page (or inside the event window content loaded) to make sure the element exists before attaching an event to it.

Hi, double check that the id for each is unique.

Learn how to use your browser devtools inspect facility and in particular check the console to see if there are any errors. Your snippet in the question is not demonstrating the problem that you describe.

Maybe this is not what you were looking for, but it seemed to me that your question was not complete in the way that you mentioned multiple buttons and divs but you didn't include them in your snippet. In cases like this it is almost always better, not to work with individual ids as this might tempt you to repeat yourself unnecessarily. Instead you should work with classes and the sequence numbers of your buttons and divs.
The below snippet is a short example of how you can achieve more functionality with fewer lines of code. And the code is easily extensible.


const divs=document.querySelectorAll(".divs");
document.querySelectorAll(".btn")
 .forEach((b,i)=>b.addEventListener('click', ()=>divs[i].classList.toggle("active")));
divs.forEach((d,i)=>d.style.left=(15+i*35)+"%");
.divs {
  display: none;
  top: 50%;
  position:absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.divs.active{ display:block }
<div>
  <button class="btn">obi</button>
  <button class="btn">nuo</button>
  <button class="btn">emi</button>
</div>
<div class="divs">obi</div>
<div class="divs">nuo</div>
<div class="divs">emi</div>



